# I am unable to to project my screen from a Windows laptop to iMac using HDMI to Thunderbolt 2

Tags: mac, imac, target-display

I am unable to project my screen as an extended screen to my Late 2012 21 inch iMac from my Dell XPS L502X.

Please guide me through steps which I can follow. I am using an HDMI to Thunderbolt 2 converter.

Comment: We really can't help you... Unless you give us the model of iMac and the exact cables you are using (links to the part on Apple.com, Amazon.com or elsewhere) And the make and model of the PC.

Comment: so you want to use the iMac as a Monitor ?

Comment: Yes, I want to use iMac as a monitor for my windows laptop.
iMac details: Model A1418 (EMC 2544)
Family Late 2012
ID         iMac13,1
RAM 8 GB
VRAM 512 MB
Storage 1 TB HDD

Answer (score 1):

> I am unable to project my screen from a windows laptop to iMac using HDMI to Thunderbolt 2

**This is impossible.**

First off, there's no such thing as HDMI to Thunderbolt (1, 2 or 3).  Thunderbolt is a multiplexing of several signals:

- DisplayPort
- PCIe Bus
- USB
- Power (Thunderbolt 3 only)

HDMI is a video signal and there's no way to convert a video signal to to anything but a video signal.

Secondly,  the requirement to use [Target Display Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204592) (assuming you have a supported iMac) is that it must *originate* from a  DisplayPort or Thunderbolt port.  It can't originate from HDMI.

Finally, the late 2012 iMac will only support a Thunderbolt connection; DisplayPort is unsupported. So, unless you have a Thunderbolt port on your laptop (your Dell L502X does not), you can't do this.

Comment: So I assume that you suggest using Mini Display port to Thunderbolt 2. My windows laptop is Dell XPS L502X. Can you suggest how I can make it work?

Comment: No.  I am saying this is impossible.  As stated in the answer, The late 2012 iMac will **only** support a Thunderbolt connection.  This Dell doesn't have one.